How to execute after validation only if all the rules passed
I am using Laravel 11.
I would like to add a rule after the validation.
Today I have this situation :
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'group_id' => 'required|uuid|exists:groups,id',
            'user_id' => [
                'required', 'uuid',
                Rule::exists('users', 'id')->where(function (Builder $query) {
                    return $query->whereIn('role_id', ['STUDENT', 'TEACHER', 'ADMIN']);
                }),
            ],.......

I added an after method :
     public function after(): array
        {
    
            return [
                function (Validator $validator) {
.......

My wish is how to execute this after method only if all the previous rules passed ?

You can check if there are any error messages on the validator. If not, all the previous rules passed. If so, at least one of the previous rules failed.
public function after(): array
{
    return [
        function (Validator $validator) {
            // Skip this validation logic if there are already validation errors.
            if ($validator->errors()->isNotEmpty()) {
                return;
            }

            // The rest of your validation logic.
        }
    ];
}


I just tried. And that's exactly what was needed. THANKS.
